# How can I get Microsoft Document Explorer, which is missing from my Delphi installation?

Tags: delphi

I installed my Delphi 2005 Personal but after running the IDE it gives me AV and some help bpl file error. I came to a conslusion that this occurs because somehow I don't have installed Microsoft Document Explorer.

Then my question is: where can I download Microsoft Document Explorer? I can't find any links myself. I think it comes with Visual Studio but I don't want to install it only to have a help system in Delphi.

**Update**
When installing Delphi I did a certain trick to not install .NET 1.0 stuff and I did wrong. There was the Microsoft Document Explorer in one of these packages. Just had to install the .NET SDK.

Comment: Did you install the help? (IIRC, Delphi 2005/2007 required a separate step during the installation in order to install help.) This should install the MS Document Explorer if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Debeet, you can answer your own question and then accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When installing Delphi I did a certain trick to not install .NET 1.0 stuff and I did wrong. There was the Microsoft Document Explorer in one of these packages. Just had to install the .NET SDK from Delphi installer.

Comment: Microsoft Document Explorer is not part of DotNet - but it uses DotNet runtime to run. So i think it got installed but just could not run lacking RTL. As you installed needed runtime it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik it is part of MSDN, but that is an huge download:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=20955

The Embarcadero FTP server might also be a smart location to check.

Comment: I believe this is a totally different help system than the old one used in D2005. It should be enough to install it from the Delphi installation.

Answer (score 0):

I found same problem when trying to install devExpress component for Delphi 2010. Problem was solved when reinstalling the help build.